# Bluetooth Beacons - Azure IoT Hub - Android App

Tags: android, azure, azure-iot-hub

I want to develop an IT system where my bluetooth beacons send data to an Azure IoT Hub. Then, I want to make an Android app to stream/pull the data from the Azure cloud. I am still new to Azure, so I do not know where to get started.

Any help (with links or example projects) would be really appreciated. I am familiar with Android App Development(currently enrolled in a college) . I am also familiar with consuming REST APIs in Android. The only help I need is how to interact with the data that is in my Azure IoT Hub?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

IoT Hub is an Azure service that enables you to ingest high volumes of telemetry from your IoT devices into the cloud for storage or processing.

We have a MS Doc to [send data from device to IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-send-telemetry-cli)

Also, we can send events from IoT hub to different end points, we can filter the data as well before sending to our endpoints. This documentation will help us in understanding to send the telemetry from [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-send-telemetry-cli) and send the data using different [SDK’s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/iot-develop/quickstart-send-telemetry-iot-hub?toc=%2Fazure%2Fiot-hub%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fiot-hub%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&pivots=programming-language-ansi-c)

This [.py file](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/azure-iot-device/samples/pnp/temp_controller_with_thermostats.py) will help us to integrate with smart devices into your solutions without any manual configuration

Can refer to [Azure SDK for Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python) to check the exact information